# Java JSON package importing failure

Tags: java, json, package

I'm working with OpenJDK 7 (openjdk-7-jdk) under Ubuntu,
compiling my code with following command

```
javac -d ./classes ./src/Program.java
```

My code contains imports

```
...
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
...
```

and i'm getting the following error

```
./src/Program.java:21: error: package javax.json does not exist
import javax.json.Json;
                 ^
./src/Program.java:22: error: package javax.json.stream does not exist
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
                        ^
```

It is curious that there is no problems with importing from javax.swing or java.util.

Please tell, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you have javax.json.* libraries in your classpath ?

Comment: echo ${CLASSPATH} gives me nothing

Comment: Upon launching `javac` command, use `-classpath` key and specify location of libraries, which contain `javax.json.*` packages. And check this link: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but i don't even know where javax.json.* packages are supposed to be. I mean javax.json is standard package,   
isn't it must be configured when installing OpenJDK?

Comment: As far as I know, I may be wrong, but OpenJDK does not contain javax.json packages as a standard library. Download javax.json jar file here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjson10jar.htm and specify it in javac classpath upon compiling and in java classpath  upon execution of your code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

steps to follow:

1. Download [javax.json jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxjson10jar.htm).
2. As you have downloaded this jar file, specify it in java compiler classpath, using javac `-classpath` key.
3. As you have your code compiled, then use `-cp` key for `java` command to specify this jar file in the runtime classpath upon your code execution.

More detailed information on classpath settings can be found here: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Comment: I have downloaded javax.json-1.0.2.jar to previously created ./lib folder, compiled program as
javac -cp ./lib/javax.json-1.0.2.jar -d ./classes ./src/Program.java
and all going fine.
Thank you!

But i'm still confusing why i need to download some standard lib manually? Why developers of OpenJDK did not include JSON to their DevKit, can anyone tell?

Comment: I do not use OpenJDK, so I don't know why does it not contain json as a standard library. Oracle Java SE JDK does not contain this library too. It is from Java Enterprise Edition SDK.

Comment: @kernelbug Answering your question: I think there are licensing issues for OpenJDK developers, and because of them they do not include this library to OpenJDK. Just my opinion.